# How to Read Timeline Seconds?

Tags: timeline

I feel pretty silly for asking, but I need to know. On the timeline sheet where it normally shows the keyframe numbers, when you go into to 'view' and you click 'show seconds' it gives you the seconds instead of keyframes.

It normally looks on the timeline like "0+00 0+03 0+06" and so on. My question is, how do you read that? Like for "0+03" is the first "0" minutes and the "03" the seconds? I just need a bit more clarification on the meaning. My frame rate is 30 FPS (in case you need to know).
I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a combination of seconds and frames.

Format = [second] + [frame number]

It starts the count of frames again for every second.
A.K.A. the frame number is relative to the seconds.

You can see it changing when you change the frame-rate of the clip in the render tab.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to mark the thread as answered so it isn't marked as unanswered unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>  on the *Timeline*, to see actual frames